# How to link any custom class to a Media entity?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

First of all, I expect this question to be a relevant one, but if it's not, then obviously that's my fault for being stupid/not searching thoroughly enough.

I've been stuck for two days on a seemingly stupid problem : **I just want to add one or more pictures to a custom class of mine**

Now the easy part is the following (as far as I know) :

- add a mapped field to the class in question (my custom entity, People)
- add a corresponding mapped field to the Media class (Media Entity from Application Bundle through EasyExtend)
- make a pass through d:s:u --force and d:g:entities for both bundle
- delete the config/doctrine directory of the Application bundle as it prevents annotations from working (seen in another thread).
- add a corresponding field in the AdminPeople.php in the AppBundle to add entities, depending on the nature of the relation, this can obviously change (I essentially use a sonata_type_model)

Now **here is the thing : I want to save the related "people id" in the corresponding column of the media__media table**

**I can't find a way to make the "people id" register in the corresponding media__media table**. The thing stays null.

What I have checked for :

- clearing the cache
- trying every possible relation mapping for the fields
- Trying to use regular setters/getters from other AdminSomething files from my regular AppBundle
- searching for every possible answer on this site, including deleting the config/doctrine directory from the the Application Bundle, changing the config.yml auto-mapping to false, trying various updates of the database (but not a complete overhaul).
- not pulling my hair out

What **I suspect** : somehow I need to override the Admin class of the Media to make the field "audible" to the class. I don't know how, and the example I found on this site did not help despite my best efforts.

What I can do :

- I can add media in their own admin section
- I can add media in foreign admin sections, BUT they won't retain the ID of the related Entity. In other words, they do appear in the media list, but NOT in the foreign admin field list.
- For regular foreign keys for other admin problems, all you have to do is get the prePersist/preUpdate to add it using getters/setters, and I can't seem to replicate that behavior right now.

Now as you guys don't like questions without code, here is mine (with extracts from my composer.json, just in case.)

**composer.json (relevant part)**

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.13",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "3.*",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/property-access": "^3.2",
    "sonata-project/dashboard-bundle": "^0.1.0"
```

**Media.php living in Application Bundle. ORM style. Properly annotated to my knowledge. Relevant bit :**

```
    /**
 * One Media has one people
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\People", inversedBy="image")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="people_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $people;
```

**People.php, again relevant part (getters and setters up to my knowledge)**

```
    /**
 * One people has one image
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy="people", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $image;
```

**The field in the PeopleAdmin.php, works great except it doesn't retain the id of the related person**

```
                ->add('image','sonata_type_model', array(
                'required'=>false,
                'by_reference'=>false,
            ))


    public function prePersist($object)
{
    foreach ($object->getImage() as $item) {
        $item->setPeople($object);
    }
}


public function preUpdate($object)
{
    foreach ($object->getImage() as $item) {
        $item->setPeople($object);
    }

}
```

Now again, when I do this, it **works** for the media part. The thing is created, is beautiful as can be (welp). Except that it doesn't persist anything related to the entity in which it was created.

Strangely (or not ? I'm not familiar with this debugging tool), I get this result upon completion (or so do I believe).

[Capture of the debugging screen of this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaZJy.png)

Thank you very much, people (eh eh).

Comment: Try to inverse the table which must keep track of the relation. In fact, you don't even need to reference People in media. Why ? Because you're more likely to do something like `$people->getMedia()` (as in PeopleAdmin) than `$media->getPeople()`

Comment: If you want to thank @mickdev more get them to post their solution below and accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Alright, the solution is simply inversing the owning side annotations from inversedBy to mappedBy and vice-versa ! 

You can post it @mickdev !

I can still do some shitty drawing by the way !